# How can I generate a material shopping list using Excel?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

This seems like it should be a fairly simple task, but I have not been able to figure it out. It should be noted that I am still new to excel, so forgive my ignorance.

I am an insulation contractor trying to streamline some of the paperwork I have to fill out for each job.
My goal is to have a workbook where I can enter data gathered from the jobsite, have it do the various calculations needed, then fill out necessary forms. The problem I am running into, is generating a Material Order List. I have simplified my example, but it illustrates what I need, and the information I am working with.

My dilema is two-part

1. How can I generate a new list of materials needed, along with the associated quantities and prices?
2. If I have the same material being used in different sections of the job, how can I consolidate them into one item on the Material Order List? (See rows 3 and 8, and rows 6 and 7)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_s-vHLiskO2MV9EbHBJVGpUMmc/edit?usp=sharing

If there is a non- Visual Basic answer, that would be ideal, as I have no experience with it. I have worked with VLOOKUP, Nested IF statement, and some others quite bit so far, but can't seem to find a function to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this structure:

```
Material Order List
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+-------+
|    Material     | Qty Needed | Coverage (each) | Price (each) | Qty | Cost  |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+-------+
| R-21 Fiberglass |        900 |              67 | 31.2         |  14 | 436.8 |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+-------+
```

For part 1, this formula in column A and filled down will return the unique Materials:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,$B$3:$B$8),0,0),0))
```

It isn't smart enough to know when to stop, but it will return `#N/A` after it has returned all the unique items. You can delete the `#N/A` rows. Or, if you prefer to have a nice long set of rows that will cover most situations, use `IFERROR` to hide the error:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,$B$3:$B$8),0,0),0)),"")
```

---

For part 2, I added an extra column for you: `Qty Needed`, which consolidates the quantity of that material needed from different sections of the job. The formula for that is

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$8,$B$3:$B$8,$A24)
```

This assumes your Order List data starts at row 24, and the Site Info is is rows 3-8 with the Insulation Type in column B.

Comment: That's perfect for my second problem! Thanks. But I would like excel to insert the material types into Column A 0f the Material Order List all on its own. I guess what I want is a formula in A25 that says '=B3', then one in A26 that says '=IF(AND(B4<>0,has not already been used),B4,IF(AND(B5<>0,has not already been used...'.       But I would like the formula to be smart enough to know when to stop looking for non-zeros and non-repeats without me having to manually type all the nested IF statements. If any of that makes any sense....

Comment: For some reason I totally glossed over the first part. I amended the answer.

Comment: I know we are supposed to avoid comments like "Thanks", But it is against my nature not to show gratitude. So.. Thanks. Copy/Pasting that formula and hitting "enter" felt like is was doing a bit of magic after trying to figure it out on my own. Obviously a bit more research into INDEX, MATCH and the various __IF functions is in order. Thanks again for pointing the way for me!

Comment: You are welcome, glad it worked for you. Credits: The Part 1 formula was adapted from [Oscar's site](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/).